# Mapping projection form hibernate HQL query into object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

I am returning only a few columns from a table in DB:

```
List<MyClass> l = (List<MyClass>) session.createQuery("Select p.one, p.two FROM MyClass p WHERE p.id IN :id")
                    .setParameter("userId", id)
                    .list();
```

However, the query returns List of arrays, e.g

```
l.get(0) // [0] is object representing p.one in query, [1] p.two
```

Is there a hibernate some effective way how to map it to MyClass object? So the query would actually return list of MyClass objects where selected properties would have values, others would be set to null?

I have read about `new MyClass(arg1,arg2)` way in the query with construtor, however i have also read it is ineffective.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use try catch block and use query.getSingleResult() to return Object.

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("FROM TipoUsuario WHERE NAME = :name;", TipoUsuario.class)
        .setParameter("name", name);

TipoUsuario tipoUsuario = null;

try
{
    tipoUsuario = (TipoUsuario) query.getSingleResult();
}
catch ( Exception e )
{
    return null;
}
```

createNativeQuery is just a sample. You can use createNamedQuery instead and put HQL in Entity with annotation @NamedQueries.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create `MyClass` you just need to use the fully-qualified name of the class in your query, e.g.

```
SELECT NEW my.pack.MyClass(p.one, p.two) FROM MyClass p WHERE p.id IN :id
```

I haven't heard of this being ineffective, and I can't image why it would be. It's just calling the constructor on the result instead of returning it as an array or object. Overall, it's probably a very good way of fetching, since you only select the fields that you need.

This and other options are also explained in more detail [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).